# Serial port hangs after first pair of read and write on linux

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port, boost-asio

I have to write a serial communication with one of the pieces of hardware in our lab.

Using bash, I can write as my times I want and receve resposnes with:

```
cat < /dev/ttyUSB0 &
echo 'SM?' >/dev/ttyUSB0
# SM=0480;
echo 'SMM=0475;' > /dev/ttyUSB0
echo 'SM?;' > /dev/ttyUSB0
# SM=0475;
```

I write an simple C++  application with asio, that should do the same.

```
#include <asio.hpp>
#include <asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <thread>

int main(){
  asio::io_service service;
  asio::serial_port port(service,"/dev/ttyUSB0");
  port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(9600));
  port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::character_size(8));
  port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::parity(asio::serial_port_base::parity::none));
  port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits(asio::serial_port_base::stop_bits::one));
  port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::flow_control( asio::serial_port_base::flow_control::none));


  std::vector<char> ret(100);
  int len;
  asio::error_code ignored;
  asio::write(port,asio::buffer("SM?;"),asio::transfer_all(),ignored);
  len=port.read_some(asio::buffer(ret),ignored);
  std::cout.write(ret.data(),len);
  asio::write(port,asio::buffer("SSM=0480;"),asio::transfer_all(),ignored);
  asio::write(port,asio::buffer("SM?;"),asio::transfer_all(),ignored);
  len=port.read_some(asio::buffer(ret),ignored);
  std::cout.write(ret.data(),len);

  std::cout << std::endl;
  port.cancel();
  port.close();
  service.stop();
  service.reset();
  return 0;
}
```

But the code hangs on the second read. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget the \n in your buffer ? `echo` adds a `'\n'` character to the string unless you call it with `-n`

strace is a great tool to debug this kind of issue.

Comment: Hmm. The hardware specification says, that the terminating char in this case is ';'. I'm out of lab for today, so I can't test it, but in that case, the first read would hang too.